# Add backgroundview with label when no search results are found

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to add a backgroundview when no search results are found. I have read through several questions/answers on this site but none have worked. I want a backgroundview to display "No Search Results" when the count of results are equal to 0.

This is what I've tried:

```
var filmsTable: UICollectionView!
var backgroundView: UIView?

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    if searchText == "" {
        self.filteredFilms = films
        self.filmsTable.reloadData()
    } else {
        self.filteredFilms = films!.filter({(($0["title"] as! String).lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))})
        //print(self.filteredFilms!.count)

if self.filteredFilms!.count == 0 {
let emptyLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.filmsTable.frame.width, height: self.filmsTable.frame.height))
    emptyLabel.text = "No Search Results"
    emptyLabel.textColor = .black
    emptyLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    emptyLabel.textAlignment = .center;
    emptyLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Times", size: 18)
    emptyLabel.sizeToFit()

    self.backgroundView = emptyLabel;
}
        self.filmsTable.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you set the `backgroundView` on the fly , you can try

```
self.filmsTable.backgroundView = emptyLabel
```

also it makes more sense if name is `filmsCollection`